# Added table cell with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am adding a table row after a button click with jQuery.  First the user picks a value from a dropdownlist.  Then the select one or many values from multi select dropdownlist and click the button.  I have a table set up that will have two columns displaying the data the user just selected.  `To display the values from the multi select dropdown I will need to do something like

```
 $('#tblDeleteInfo').append("<tr><td>" + $('#ddlDeleteUPC :selected').text() + "</td><td>" +
                $('#ddlDeleteUPCStores :selected').each(function (sel) {
                    append(($(this).text() + "  "));
                })
            + "</td></tr>");
```

but inside the loop I will need to do something to append the text the table cell I just generated....  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your html? what is tblDeleteInfo? is it tr or table itself?

Comment: That should help.  Sorry about that

Comment: Need the HTML too. A jsFiddle would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGSqh/)

```
var tableRow = "<td>";
tableRow += $('#ddlDeleteUPC :selected').text();
tableRow += "</td><td>";
$('#ddlDeleteUPCStores :selected')
    .each(function (sel) {
                tableRow += $(this).text();
    });
tableRow += "</td>";
$('#tblDeleteInfo').append("<tr>" + tableRow + "</tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#ddlDeleteStores :selected').each(function (sel) {
        $('#tblDeleteInfo').append("<td>"+ ( $(this).text() + "  ") +"</td>");
    });
```

Comment: that would put each result in its own cell.  I am trying to put them all in one